# Text getting blur on zoom-in

Tags: iphone, zooming

I have requirement in which I have tableview as a subview of imageview. Now when the user zooms-in , the text inside the tableview is getting blur. Is there any way to manipulate it at time of zoom-in?

Comment: code is simple zoom in code implementation via viewForZooming of scrollview. I dont have any problem with implementation perspective. I want to know the solution of text getting blured during zoom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass label as follows :

TiledLable.h file ::

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FastCATiledLayer.h"
@interface TiledLable : UILabel 
{

}

@end
```

TiledLale.m file ::

```
#import "TiledLable.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation TiledLable

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Initialization code.
        FastCATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (FastCATiledLayer *)[self layer];
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 2;
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 2;
        tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(1024.0,1024.0);
        tiledLayer.contents = nil;
        self.layer.contents = nil;
    }
    return self;
}


// Set the layer's class to be CATiledLayer.
+ (Class)layerClass 
{
    return [FastCATiledLayer class];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    ((CATiledLayer *)[self layer]).delegate = nil;    
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    [self.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps which is below.
Don't set the position of image statically i mean by giving coordinate.Set the position dynamically or at the run time it will take position based on current window or zoom in zoom out position label,i am not pretty much sure because i havn't faced this situation earlier but as i think it might be use case scenario for solving your problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it by subclassing CALayer for labels. Thanks all for help.

Comment: Can you share the method you used to achieve this?

Comment: @AVeryDev I had posted the answer which i used. Use this subclassed label instead of UIlabel